# Concatenate List of Characters Recursively in Common LISP

Tags: recursion, encryption, lisp, concatenation, common-lisp

So I'm attempting to implement a Caesar cipher in LISP recursively, and I've got the basic functionality working. The problem is it returns a list of characters, and calling concatenate 'string on the return statement just returns the same list of characters plus a "". What am I doing wrong here?

```
(defun caesar (s n) 
    (if (null (concatenate 'list s))
        '()
        (cons 
            (code-char (+ n (char-code (car (concatenate 'list s))))) 
            (caesar (coerce (cdr (concatenate 'list s)) 'string) n)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Half of your program seems to be missing: specificallt `stringtolist`

Comment: Oops, accidentally provided old code, updated

Comment: Without any formatting, your code is unreadable. You might want to format your code. It is expected that you put a minimum of effort into your questions.

Comment: you're right, sorry I'm a little new to lisp

Comment: What should something like `(concatenate 'list s)` do? Here is the documentation: [concatenate](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_concat.htm#concatenate). Probably it is something like coerce? But you are calling it multiple times. I would not convert lists to strings and strings to lists all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The right approach to something like this is to do the conversion between string & list in a wrapper of some kind  & then have the main function work on the list.

Here is an approach to doing that which uses some of the power and elegance of CL.  This:

- uses CLOS methods to do wrapping -- this will presumably make it ineligible for submission as homework, in case that is what it is, but is a good demonstration of how pretty CLOS can be I think, and is also how I would actually write something like this;
- uses `coerce` in the wrapper method rather than `concatenate` to change types, since that's what it's for;
- intentionally does *not* deal with some of the other problems of the original code around recursion & char-codes.

First of all here is a version which uses two methods: a wrapper method (defined in the generic function definition for convenience) and then the recursive method which does the work:

```
(defgeneric caesar (text n)
  (:method ((text string) n)
   ;; if we're given a string just turn it into a list, then recurse
   ;; on the list & turn it back to a string (of the same type, hence
   ;; TYPE-OF).
   (coerce (caesar (coerce text 'list) n) (type-of text))))

(defmethod caesar ((text list) n)
  ;; The recursive level (note this has various issues which are in
  ;; the original code & not addressed here
  (if (null text)
      '()
    (cons (code-char (+ n (char-code (first text))))
          (caesar (rest text) n))))
```

Secondly here is a slightly too-clever approach, using a special termination-on-`null` method.  I would not recommend this, but it's a neat demonstration of the kind of thing CLOS can do.

```
(defgeneric caesar (text n)
  (:method ((text string) n)
   ;; if we're given a string just turn it into a list, then recurse
   ;; on the list & turn it back to a string (of the same type, hence
   ;; TYPE-OF).
   (coerce (caesar (coerce text 'list) n) (type-of text))))

(defmethod caesar ((text null) n)
  ;; termination
  '())

(defmethod caesar ((text list) n)
  ;; The recursive level (note this has various issues which are in
  ;; the original code & not addressed here
  (cons (code-char (+ n (char-code (first text))))
        (caesar (rest text) n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to combine with-output-to-string and labels (for the recursive bit):

```
(defun caesar (s n)
  (with-output-to-string (cipher)
    (labels ((beef (s)
               (when s
                  (princ <whatever> cipher)
                  (beef (rest s)))))
      (beef (coerce s 'list)))))
```

Caveat: the above is thoroughly untested and simply typed into this message, so likely will not even compile. It just makes the suggestions more cncrete.